# Помогите распарсить `VkApiAudio` в виде `json`

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Помогите распарсить `VkApiAudio` в виде `json`

У меня так:

```
if (attachment.getType().equals(VKAttachments.TYPE_AUDIO)){
                final VKApiAudio audio = (VKApiAudio) attachment;
                Log.d("TAG", "audio title: " + audio.url);
```

Но все приходит, кроме `audio.url`. Может можно как нить распарсить все это в виде `json`????

Что то типа:

```
JSONArray att = (JSONArray) item.getJSONArray("attachments"); JSONObject xx = (JSONObject) att.get(0); 
img = xx.getJSONObject("audio").getString("url"); 
Log.d("MSCurrentPost", "JSON: " + img);
```

Comment: Вроде ВК в декабре убрали музыку из АПИ и её получить так больше нельзя

Comment: А как можно теперь?

Comment: Цитата: Вы можете связаться с нами по адресу api@vk.com, если Ваш продукт: 
1. Является единственным в своем роде, обладает уникальной функциональностью; 
2. Представляет собой полноценный клиент с широкой аудиторией — то есть, поддерживает работу со всеми основными сервисами ВКонтакте, включая новостную ленту и сообщения; 
3. Предполагает использование исключительно свободно распространяемого контента.  ............ https://vk.com/dev/audio_api

Comment: А вообще можно распарсить все это под json? Просто вообще не шарю в этом....